# jquery ui dialog not appearing on page with Google Maps v3

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3

There seems to be a problem using the jQuery UI Dialog on the same page as Google maps on some versions of iPad/iOS Safari.

The following code displays a map with a link underneath. Clicking the link should pop up a basic jQuery UI dialog.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#mapcontainer {
    width:50%;
    height:300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- ## Map Container ## -->
<div id="mapcontainer"></div>

<!-- ## Show Dialog ## -->
<a id="showdialog" href="#">Show Dialog</a>

<!-- ## Dialog ## -->
<div id="mydialog"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    initMap();
    $('#showdialog').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#mydialog').dialog();
    });
});

function initMap() {
    if (google.maps != null && typeof google.maps === 'object') {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcontainer'), mapOptions);
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It seems to work fine on the newer desktop browsers and on an Android device (native browser and Chrome). However on the iPad (iOS 5.1.1 Safari) nothing happens when clicking the link. On the iOS simulator it appears to function correctly on Safari in iOS 6.1 but not in 5.1 or lower.

One possible solution seems to be to force 3D acceleration using something like this in the css:

```
*:not(html) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

but it seems likely this may cause other problems on pages heavy in graphical elements.

Is there some other way that would be safer?

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-dialog * {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Ur welcome. U saved my day actually. =)